# Draw mirrored in C# using System.Drawing.Graphics

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, transform, mirror

I have written a little helper function which performs some sort of drawing operations, which are rather complex.

I call this function out of another class which sometimes applies transformations to it. Rotating and translating works fine, but now I want to force the helper function to draw the whole thing mirrored over the y-axis.

I tried to use

```
g.ScaleTransform(0, -1);
```

before calling the helper function, but it threw an exception.

So, how is it possible to draw mirrored using a System.Drawing.Graphics object?

Comment: Argument Exception: Parameter is not valid.

When calling g.ScaleTransform(0, -1);

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to call

```
g.ScaleTransform(1, -1);
```

Note that now your image will be drawn behind the upper screen edge. To fix it, you need to call `g.TranslateTransform` before `g.ScaleTransform`:

```
g.TranslateTransform(0, YourImageHeightHere);
g.ScaleTransform(1, -1);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how it's done with a BitMap, you can draw the image from the graphics and redraw the graphics object with the modified one.

```
    public Bitmap MirrorImage(Bitmap source)
    {
        Bitmap mirrored = new Bitmap(source.Width, source.Height);
        for(int i = 0; i < source.Height; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < source.Width; j++)
                mirrored.SetPixel(i, j, source.GetPixel(source.Width - j - 1, i);
        return mirrored;
    }
```

Edit: @MattSlay, thanks it was a typo, I fixed it.

Comment: I don't want to transform a bitmap, I want to draw mirrored lines, rectangles, paths and so on with a graphics object. Furthermore, images natively support flipping (mirroring): http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.drawing.image.rotateflip(VS.80).aspx But thanks for the help nevertheless.

Comment: This is really slow. If you want to manipulate single pixels, use Bitmap.LockBits(), see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d.aspx

Comment: This pattern does work. I tried the code, but I had to change " j > source.Width " to " j < source.Width